# Enumeration of $\mathbb Q^n$ such that the distance of consecutive points is $1$ in some norm of $\mathbb R^n$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

For which $n \in \mathbb N$ , does there exist a bijection $f : \mathbb N \to \mathbb Q^n$ and a norm $\|\cdot\|$ on $\mathbb R^n$ such that $\|f(k+1)-f(k)\|=1, \forall k \in \mathbb N$ ?

Comment: Please add some context for this Question.  What motivates this problem?

Comment: @hardmath : in any norm $||.||$ of $\mathbb R^n$ , $\inf \{||x-y|| : x,y \in \mathbb Q^n , x \ne y\}=0$ , so I just wanted to see If I could arrange the points so as to make the distance some specified constant ...

Comment: You should add that context to the question, rather than posting a comment.

Comment: @DanielFischer : Honestly , it feels a little embarrassing to have to provide a context to such an interesting question ... I think it might have come to almost everyone's mind subconsciously  once in a lifetime ...

Comment: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: @DanielFischer : Please feel free to edit if you absolutely deem it necessary ...

Answer (score 3):

When $n= 1$, up to a multiplicative constant the absolute value is the only norm, and it is easy to see that there is no solution.

When $n\geq 2$, however, there are always solutions, if we take $||.||$ to be the "max" norm defined by $||(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)||_{\infty}=\max(|x_k|; 1\leq k \leq n)$. Note that there is no solution if we take
an irrational multiple of this norm, for example $||x||=\sqrt{2}||x||_{\infty}$ (because for this norm, points in ${\mathbb Q}^n$ are always at irrational distances from each other).

A natural way to solve the problem is to start with any enumeration of ${\mathbb Q}^n$
and iterate (using the axiom of choice) the following procedure : given any point $a$ in ${\mathbb Q}^n$ not yet enumerated by $f$, find a finite path between $a$ and $b$ (where
$b$ is the last point enumerated by $f$ so far), consisting only of not-yet-enumerated-by-$f$ points, and such that the distance between two successive points
in the path is always $1$. This motivates the following definition :

**Definition.** Let $a,b\in{\mathbb Q}^n$. A finite path $(v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_N)$ in ${\mathbb Q}^n$ is $(N,a,b)$-nice iff $v_0=a,v_N=b$ and $||v_{k+1}-v_k||_{\infty}=1$ for $0\leq k \lt N$.

The procedure described above actually works, thanks to the following lemma :

**LEMMA 1.** Let $a,b\in{\mathbb Q}^n$ and let $X$ be any finite subset of ${\mathbb Q}^n$. Then, there is a finite $(N,a,b)$-nice path $(v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_N)$ such that  $v_k\not\in X$ for $1\leq k \leq N-1$.

This lemma clearly follows from another lemma :

**LEMMA 2.** Let $a,b\in{\mathbb Q}^n$. Then, there is a $N\in{\mathbb N}$ such that
the set of all $(N,a,b)$-nice paths (denote it by ${\cal N}(N,a,b)$) has the property that the projection $\lbrace v_k | (v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_N) \in {\cal N}(N,a,b) \rbrace$ is infinite for $1\leq k \leq N-1$.

Using concatenation and working one coordinate at a time, it suffices to show lemma 2 when
$a$ and $b$ differ by only one coordinate, the first, say: $a_1\neq b_1$. We may assume without loss that $a_1<b_1$.

**LEMMA 3.** Let $a_1<b_1$ in $\mathbb Q$. Then there is an odd $N$ such that the set
${\cal M}(N,a_1,b_1)$ of all sequences $(w_0,w_1,\ldots,w_N)\in{\mathbb Q}^{N+1}$ with $w_0=a_1,w_N=b_1$, and $|w_{k+1}-w_k| \leq 1$ for $0\leq k \lt N$ has the property that the projection $\lbrace w_k | (w_0,w_1,\ldots,w_N) \in {\cal M}(N,a,b) \rbrace$ is infinite for $1\leq k \leq N-1$.

**Proof of lemma 2 (from lemma 3)** To go from $(w_0,w_1,\ldots,w_N)\in{\cal M}(N,a_1,b_1)$ to $(v_0,v_1,\ldots,v_N)\in{\cal N}(N,a,b)$, define
$v_k=(w_k,a_2+\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2},a_3+\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2},\ldots,a_n+\frac{1+(-1)^k}{2})$.

**Proof of lemma 3.** Using concatenation again, and considering the integer part of $b_1-a_1$, it suffices to show lemma 3 when $|b_1-a_1| \leq 1$. In that case, we may take $N=3$ since all the $(a_1,x,b_1)$ for $x \in (a_1,b_1)$ are in ${\cal M}(3,a_1,b_1)$ . This finishes the proof.

Comment: So for $n=1$ case , we would basically have $|f(k+1)-f(k)|=|f(m+1)-f(m)|, \forall m , k \in \mathbb N$ ...  I can't immediately see why this is not possible ...

Comment: @users Since norms are translation-invariant, one can assume that $f(0) = 0$. Let $c = \lVert 1\rVert$. Then there are two choices for $f(1)$, either $f(1) = 1/c$ or $f(1) = -1/c$. By induction, the conditions that $f$ be injective and that $\lVert f(k+1) - f(k)\rVert = 1$ for all $k$ imply that $f(k) = k\cdot f(1)$ for all $k\in \mathbb{N}$.